# Closed form for 2D lattice sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions

I am wondering if a closed form exists to the lattice sum
$$S(a)= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(a^2+m^2+n^2)^{3/2}}$$
I am also interested in replacing $m^2+n^2$ with a general positive definite quadratic form.

Comment: For the record, I know the large $a$ asymptotics (via Riemann Sums) and I've consulted _Lattice Sums Then and Now_ by Borwein et al.

Comment: $=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(3/2)} \int_0^\infty e^{-\pi a^2 x} \theta(x)^2 x^{1/2}dx, \theta(x) = \sum_{n} e^{- \pi n^2 x}$

Comment: When $a = 0$, this is (morally) the value of the zeta function of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ at $s = 3/2$. Since it's non-critical, it's probably just a mysterious number.

Comment: I worry (may need to accept) that variants of @reuns expression may be as good as it gets. I get $\theta(x) \sim 1/\sqrt{x}$ near $x=0$, so the integral converges.